# Using R to perform a PCA on melted variables

Tags: r, pca, reshape2

I have a dataset where I've measured gene expression of 21 genes and also measured the output of 3 other assays. I have measured these for 8 different clones. I have also measured these on 5 different days.

However, I haven't measured every gene or assay on every day, or for every clone.  So I have datasets of varying lengths.  In order to easily combine them into one large dataset, to perform a PCA on them, I melted each dataset and then row bound them.  I then standardized all the values. I now have a dataset that looks like the below.

What I want to do is a PCA where each of the factors in "group" is calculated in the PCA. Then, I'd like to create graphs where different colors of datapoints represent different "clones" or "days". I've pasted my sad attempt to get that working below. Any help would be appreciated!

```
set.seed(1)

# Creates variables for a dataset
    clone <- sample(c(rep(c("1A","2A","2B","3B","3C"), each=100),rep(c("1B","2C","3A"), each=200)))
    day <- sample(c(rep(1,225),rep(2,25),rep(3,600),rep(4,25),rep(5,225)))
    group <- sample(c(rep(paste0("gene",1:21), each=42),rep("assay1",90),rep("assay2",80),rep("assay3",48)))
    value = rnorm(1100, mean=0, sd=3)

# Create data frame from variables
    df <- data.frame(clone,day,group,value)
    df$day <- as.factor(df$day)

# Create PCA data
        df_PCA <- prcomp(clone + day + group ~ value, data = df, scale = FALSE)

# Graphing results of PCA
        par(mfrow=c(2,3))
            plot(df_PCA$x[,1:2], col=clone)
            plot(df_PCA$x[,1:2], col=day)
            plot(df_PCA$x[,1:3], col=clone)
            plot(df_PCA$x[,1:3], col=day)
            plot(df_PCA$x[,2:3], col=clone)
            plot(df_PCA$x[,2:3], col=day)
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "each of the factors in `group` is calculated in the PCA"? Do you want to run a separate PCA within each group? Or are you looking for the PCA to line up with the `group` levels?

Comment: I'd liek the PCA to line up with the group levels. So, all the data in the dataset above to be used.

Comment: Given the structure of your data, it would make more sense to use a clustering technique. PCA is essentially a way of grouping variables that share a certain level of variance - this doesn't apply with this form of data. Check out `hclust()` or `kmeans()` for a start.